# Facebook User webhooks comment

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have set up user web-hooks for my Facebook Application successfully. I get a callback when a post is added to a user's feed but it only returns the id of the user, and the field that changed (in this case `feed`). This works when new content is posted to the user's feed, but when a new comment is added to an older post on that user's feed, it still only returns the id of the user, and the `feed` field.

Is there anyway to know which post a comment was made on without paging through the entire user's feed?